# How to switch states insight angular modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal

What I want to do is having a modal and insight it have 2 states (login and signup). Tried it first with bootstrap but i couldn't make it work having 2 different states and after some research found a good example

```
http://embed.plnkr.co/DJP7sp/preview
```

The problem with the example is that when i close the modal, I cannot open it again without refreshing the page (had to change the example to backdrop: true to be able to close the modal). Does anyone know why?
Also, I found Angular Modal Service, but couldn't find anything about having different state views insight the modal again.
Thanks!

Comment: Speaking as a user ... is there anyway to *not* have it as a modal?

Comment: yes of course but I want it to be a modal that pops up